# I want to perform a multi-set intersection using C++

Tags: c++, set, multiset, set-intersection

I am using `std::set<int>` and multi-set classes `std::multiset<int>` to perform some set operations - union, intersection etc. The problem is that I have to perform intersection between two multi-sets such that I also get the duplicate values. The intersection works fine when I use it with simple sets (not multi-sets) e.g.

Set1={1,2,3,4,5,6}
Set2={4,5,6,7,8,9}
then the
std::set_intersection give me a correct result which is {4,5,6}

However, if I have a multiset

multi-set1{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6}
multi-set2{4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9}

and I again use the std::set_intersection it again gives me the result {4,5,6}

which is not correct, because the actual intersection is {4,4,5,5,6,6}

Although I am using a multi-set to hold the results of intersection, still I get the wrong answer.

Can anyone tell me how can I solve this issue.

Comment: As a workaround, does your implementation allow using std::set of vectors, and then the set_intersection will return the vectors which will contain all of the elements that you need?

Comment: So for each `{elememt,count}` you want the min of count between the two multisets in the output?

Comment: Thanks, everyone may be I can do it with vectors but I prefer if I have a solution with sets because they are everywhere in my code. I just want to the result that I showed in my example. I don't want the duplicate elements to be considered as duplicates but an individual number. @Yakk Yes something like that which you just said

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. The `set_intersection` is clearly specified to have the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: "Constructs a sorted range beginning at d_first consisting of elements that are found in both sorted ranges [first1, last1) and [first2, last2). If some element is found m times in [first1, last1) and n times in [first2, last2), the first std::min(m, n) elements will be copied from the first range to the destination range. The order of equivalent elements is preserved. The resulting range cannot overlap with either of the input ranges. " ,yes very clear.  Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would you please post your code to check if there are mistakes?
I have coded an  intersection example like the code below and it works.

```
multiset<int> ms1;
ms1.insert(1);
ms1.insert(1);
ms1.insert(1);
ms1.insert(2);
ms1.insert(3);

multiset<int> ms2;
ms2.insert(1);
ms2.insert(1);
ms2.insert(2);
ms2.insert(2);
ms2.insert(4);

vector<int> v(10);
set_intersection( ms1.begin(), ms1.end(), ms2.begin(), ms2.end(), v.begin() );
```

the result is 1, 1, 2. which is correct!

Comment: Try adding an extra `1` into `ms2` and see what you get.

Comment: @NathanOliver nothing wrong. still correct answer. remember to increase size of vector v to 11 :) well, size of vector must be according to size of sets. the first one I submitted had a bug.

Comment: Yep.  My bad.  Had it backwards

Comment: Please reformat this to be an answer, not a long comment asking for feedback from the OP.  It contains an answer; make it prominant.

Comment: @Syed I couldn't add a new comment, so I comment here. I don't see anything wrong with code posted below. Are you sure both m_ecb_all and m_pcb_j are declared as multisets?

Comment: @NathanOliver I had a query on how to do this if we have a multiset of objects? I have a class A and i made a multiset of A ie. `std::multiset<A, cmp_A> a`. here cmp_A is a comparator class for A that i had created. Its giving me a lot of errors when i do this(like a page of error). Any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: @Jamāl You need `set_intersection( set1.begin(), set1.end(), set2.begin(), set2.end(), vector.begin(), cmpA );`

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh ok. I actually want the result as multiset again. So i did something like the answer below. Im not using vector.

Comment: @Jamāl Then replace `vector.begin()` with `std::inserter(name_of_multiset, intersection.begin())`

Comment: @NathanOliver I did exactly that and got a tonne of errors. Here is the pastebin link if you want to have a look https://pastebin.com/0GAunMW9

Comment: @Jamāl This isn't really the place to debug your problem.  If you're having a problem getting the code working, ask a question and put it in a [mre]

Answer (score 2):

set_intersection actually performs intersection for multisets, too. I assume your call of set_intersection was wrong. There are few requirements you must meet, described in reference, for example:

> The resulting range cannot overlap with either of the input ranges.

However, see the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator> // inserter
#include <algorithm> // set_intersection
#include <set> // multiset

int main() {
    std::multiset<int> set1 = { 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6 };
    std::multiset<int> set2 = { 4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9 };
    std::multiset<int> intersection;
    std::set_intersection(set1.begin(), set1.end(), set2.begin(), set2.end(), std::inserter(intersection, intersection.begin()));

    // prints: 4 4 5 5 6 6 
    for(int elem : intersection) {
        std::cout << elem << ' ';
    } 
}
```